# True for real numbers is also true for complex numbers

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

For real number we can prove by induction $x$ it is true that $|\sin nx|\leq n|\sin x|$ but is this true for complex numbers $z$ i.e. is it true $|\sin nz|\leq n|\sin z|; z\in \mathbb{C}$?

Comment: What is your definition of the complex sine? And have you just tried with one or three random non-real complex numbers and seen what happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that $\sin(iz)=i\sinh(z).$ So, it is enough to prove that the inequality with hyperbolic sine does not hold for some positive integer $n.$ Lets look at the [graph of $$y=\dfrac{\sinh (2x)}{\sinh(x)}.$$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot+y%3Dsinh%282x%29%2Fsinh%28x%29) Clearly it is not bounded by $2.$

Comment: Actually, a sort of the opposite inequality works for purely imaginary arguments as $\Bigg\lvert\dfrac{\sinh (n x)}{\sinh(x)}\Bigg\rvert\ge n$ for all $n$ positive integer values.